# How to solve System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, php, web-services, nullreferenceexception

I am calling a web service in my php page. The web services are in C#. When I try to call a method using soap client object, it displays me error like:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The code I use to call Web service method is :

```
 $Username = "username";
 $Password = "password";
 $LifetimeRequest = 60*60*24;


$soap_data = array(
   'Username' => $Username,
   'Password' => $Password,
   'LifetimeRequest' => $LifetimeRequest
);
$client = new SoapClient('http://50.56.173.161:8502/AdomniService.svc?wsdl');
$response = $client->ClientLogin($soap_data);
var_dump($response);
```

When I use `var_dump` it shows output like:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["ClientLoginResult"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
    ["Error"]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (5) {
      ["Private"]=>
      float(2)
      ["Public"]=>
      int(1)
      ["Details"]=>
      string(284) "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Adomni.AdomniService.ClientLogin(ClientLoginRequest request) in C:\Users\megiddo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Adomni\AdOmniAPIService\AdomniService\AdomniClientService.svc.cs:line 107"
      ["ErrorCode"]=>
      int(0)
      ["ErrorMessage"]=>
      NULL
    }
    ["Status"]=>
    int(-1)
    ["Token"]=>
    object(stdClass)#5 (8) {
      ["Private"]=>
      float(2)
      ["Public"]=>
      int(1)
      ["EventNotificationUri"]=>
      NULL
      ["IsManager"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["LifetimeRequest"]=>
      int(0)
      ["Password"]=>
      NULL
      ["TokenId"]=>
      int(0)
      ["UserName"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

The code which was used in C# is like:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using AdOmniWebPortal.AdOmniService;

namespace AdOmniWebPortal
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void AdOmniLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            AdomniServiceClient Client = new AdomniServiceClient();
            LoginRequest LoginRequest = new LoginRequest();
            LoginResponse LoginResponse = new LoginResponse();

            LoginRequest.Username = AdOmniLogin.UserName;
            LoginRequest.Password = AdOmniLogin.Password;
            LoginRequest.LifetimeRequest = 60*60*24;
            //This guy will be changed
            LoginRequest.EventNotificationURL = new Uri("http://herp-a-derp.com/awesome.html");

            LoginResponse = Client.Login(LoginRequest);

            if (LoginResponse.Status == 0)
            {
                System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(LoginResponse.Token.UserName, true);
                LifetimeToken token = LoginResponse.Token;
                Session["Token"] = token;

                GetUserRequest request = new GetUserRequest() { Token = token };
                GetUserResponse response = Client.GetUser(request);

                if (response.GetUser.Type == AdOmniService.UserType.Seller)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Seller/SellerHomeDashboard.aspx");
                }

                if (response.GetUser.Type == AdOmniService.UserType.Client)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Buyer/BuyerHomeDashboard.aspx");
                }

                if (response.GetUser.Type == AdOmniService.UserType.None)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Buyer/BuyerHomeDashboard.aspx");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
                Response.Write(LoginResponse.Error.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have put the whole .cs page content in Edit.

Comment: You are getting a response back that is telling you the ClientLogin failed. Contact the owner of the webservice what the error message means.

Comment: Can you call the web service from a .net client?

Comment: yes Marcus. It is already running in .net. I have to use the same web services in my php pages.

Comment: i would look more at the object ClientLoginRequest, that you are passing, compare this object with both platforms PHP,C# and see if the PHP version is missing a piece of data?

Comment: NullObjectReference suggestes something is missing or not available

Comment: What is the content of the `line 107` in the `domniClientService.svc.cs` file?

Comment: hi Alex, now that is the problem. because I dont have access to that file. I can't really tell you what is in that file.

Comment: I would look more into LoginRequest..

Comment: Hi marcus, I have added the C# code which calls the same method. you can see that it also uses only 3 values Usernam, Password and LifetimeRequest.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya - If you don't have access to the file, you can't fix it. You need to contact the developer of the web service.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya - There isn't enough code in the edit to determine where the issue lies. For instance from what I can see `AdOmniLogin` is not assigned and would cause this problem but pasting more code might reveal its instantiated elsewhere providing its not static ... Need more code.

Comment: hi webnoob, I have pasted whole Login.cs page content in edit.

Comment: Could you also post the definition of the `LoginRequest` class? Is the code working from the C# or it fails there as well as in the PHP script?

Answer (score 1):

Use Fiddler (a http debug proxy)

that will allow you to peak inside of the request being made to the web service (in xml format)

so you can see if you are missing anything.

channel your c# client through fiddler, and take a look

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your PHP script, you should also set the `EventNotificationURL` variable.

Take a look at this section in the error response:

```
  ["EventNotificationUri"]=>
  NULL
```

Maybe the service expects you to pass in a `EventNotificationUri` value, just like you pass in the the `Password`, `Username` and `LifetimeRequest`.

**[EDIT]**

Try to change your variable name from `Username` to `UserName`. As far as I found out, PHP should be case sensitive in this matter, so `"Username" != "UserName"`

Comment: Hi Alex. I've tried adding ["EventNotificationUri"]. But it does not affect the output. And it is an optional field.

Comment: You should really contact the developers of the web service. What about my last comment under your question? Could you provide some more info, as I requested?

Comment: Hi Alex, I have checked it in C# and it is working fine there. I have contacted the developers regarding to this issue. Hope they will come up with some solution. :)